# Правописание прилагательного от имени собственного

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование

Как правильно — Павликин папа или папа Павлика? Шурикин мяч или мяч Шурика?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В современном языке притяжательные прилагательные с суффиксами ИН и ОВ обычно заменяются существительными в Р.п.: мяч Шурки, папа Павлика.

**Сфера применения прилагательные с суффиксами ИН и ОВ очень узка ― это разговорная речь (фамильярно-бытовые и семейно-домашние отношения) и художественные произведения:**  мамин, папин, тетин, дядин, Маша ― Машин, Миша ― Мишин, Шурка ― Шуркин (**от существительных на А**); отцов, дедов, Иван ― Иванов  (Иваново детство).

Павликин, Павликов, Шурикин, Шуриков, Иванов ― эти притяжательные формы обычно являются фамилиями, поэтому они вытесняют из литературного языка в язык разговорный и просторечный прилагательные со значением индивидуальной принадлежности.

При ответе использован материал из книги Бельчиков Ю.А. "Практическая стилистика современного языка"

Comment: *Павликин...  Шурикин* - это что ж за персонажи такие Павлика и Шурика? Юлия Абрамовича порождения?

Comment: А  Юлий Абрамович тут при чем?  Я  использую материалы из книги, но не копирую их. Павликины, Шурикины - реальные русские фамилии, а Павликина книжка - это чисто разговорный вариант (бытовой, как говорит Юлий Абрамович).

Answer (score 1):

Второй вариант абсолютно правильный, а первый встречается редко. Если мяч не Шурика, а Шуры или Шурки, то "Шурин и Шуркин мяч" – абсолютно правильно. В учебнике пятого класса читаем: "Мишины тетради, Муркины котята".
Думаю, что и Шурикин мяч не ошибка, и Павликин папа.

Ой, нет... Павликов папа и Шуриков мяч.

Answer (score 0):

Если он - Шурик, то ***Шуриков [мяч]***. Если "Шурика" (такое бывает?), то Шурикин.

Аналогично с Павликом. 
Притяжательные формы на "-ин" образуются от слов первого (школьного) склонения на -а/-я мужского и женского рода, и третьего склонения женского рода. На "-ов" - от слов мужского (реже - среднего) рода второго склонения.

В отношении их распространенности. Замена совершенно необязательна. Такие формы сейчас не слишком продуктивны (видимо отсюда и ваша неуверенность), но отнюдь не устарели. Правда пользоваться ими рекомендуется главным образом в разговорном стиле. В деловом - да, лучше заменить на родительный падеж.